# How to Create a Reusable Query Function with Custom Options in React Query and Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I'm working with React Query and Axios for API requests. Currently, I have a function registerByEmail that handles registration using Axios and defines a useRegisterByEmail hook for mutations. Here's the existing setup:

```
export interface ApiResponseInterface<T> {
  status: string
  statusCode: number
  result: T
}

export interface ErrorApiResponseInterface {
  statusCode: number
  error: string
  message: string[]
}

export interface RegisterByEmailBodyInterface {
  email: string
  username: string
  password: string
}

export interface RegisterByEmailResultInterface {}

export const registerByEmail = async (body: RegisterByEmailBodyInterface) => {
  return await axios.post<ApiResponseInterface<RegisterByEmailResultInterface>>(
    "/auth/email/register",
    body
  )
}

export const useRegisterByEmail = () =>
  useMutation({
    mutationFn: registerByEmail,
    mutationKey: ["register"],
  })
```

Now, I aim to make the useRegisterByEmail hook more versatile by allowing custom options to be passed in. Here's the desired modification:

```
export const useRegisterByEmail = (options) =>
  useMutation({
    mutationFn: registerByEmail,
    mutationKey: ["register"],
    ...options
  })
```

How can I implement this modification while ensuring correct typing and handling of options within the useRegisterByEmail hook? I'm specifically looking to enhance its reusability by incorporating customizable options effectively.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or examples demonstrating the correct approach to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use mine:

```js
// Api.ts
import config from './Global'

const Api = {
  post: (route: any, data: any, conf: any) => {
    return config.axiosHandle().post(`${route}`, data, conf)
  },
  delete: (route: any, conf: any) => {
    return config.axiosHandle().delete(`${route}`, conf)
  },
  get: (route: any, dataCom = '', conf: any) => {
    const data = dataCom
    const qs =
      '?' +
      Object.keys(data)
        .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[+key])}`)
        .join('&')

    return config.axiosHandle().get(`${route}${dataCom !== '' ? qs : ''}`, conf)
  }
}

export default Api
```

```js
// Global.ts
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const config = {
  udata: Cookies.get('token'),
  axiosHandle: () => {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: '',
      validateStatus: function (status: any) {
        if (status === 401) localStorage.clear()

        return status >= 200 && status < 300
      },
      headers: config.udata
        ? {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + config.udata
        }
        : {}
    })
  }
}
export default config
```

```
// Request.ts
import Api from './Api'

export const MerchantsRequest = (shopId: string, fn: (arg0: any) => void) => {
  Api.get(`/api/Merchants/GetMerchantListFilterId?ShopId=${shopId}`, '', '')
    .then((response: any) => {
      fn(response.data.result.dbData)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

u can use it like:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if (merchant != undefined)
      MerchantsRequest(merchant, x => {
        setIsLoading(false)

        setMerchants(x)
      })
  }, [merchant])
```